# How to upload a csv file dynamically (through apex) in salesforce

Tags: csv

I have a requirement to upload csv file through apex. I should allow user to browser csv from their own system and insert that csv somewhere in my org. Will it possible. Thanks in advance

Current Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="AttachmentUploadController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Visualforce Example" subtitle="Attachment Upload Example"/> 
        <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <apex:pageMessages /> 
                <apex:pageBlock title="Upload a Attachment">
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
```

I don't want to store the CSV file in `Notes and Attachments`.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  This requires Visualforce and you should Google this topic as this problem has been addressed many times

Comment: I know that we can't insert file into static resource through apex

Comment: @Satya It is a very common scenario and yes it is possible. There should be already some threads in this forum.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it sounds like a 'do it for me' question, and doesn't show any attempt at research. If you [edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/157596/edit) to include more details about where you're stuck, how similar questions haven't solved your issue, and provide the code that you currently have, then I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: @derek my question is whr can I store this csv. I dnt want to store in notes and attachments. I tired to insert in static resource. Throwing exception can't perform dml like . Had posted my vf page

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! It looks like you attempted to add code into the 'edit summary' portion of the edit page instead of editing the actual text of your question. I've fixed that as much as I was able, but you'll have to complete the edits. I've retracted my downvote.

Comment: @Satya without knowing what you want to do with the CSV that is hard to answer. Static Resources are not available to edit in the Apex API and must be edited in the Metadata API. You could use Content or Documents to store your CSV depending on your business requirements.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about why you want to avoid uploading to `Notes and Attachments`? Honestly, uploading as an attachment is probably the easiest way to do this. The only other dedicated 'document storage' on Salesforce that I know of is in a `Content Library` (which is a lot more work to use, and may incur an additional monthly charge from Salesforce).

Comment: From csv I'll read the records of account. After reading I'll check whether any duplicate records are there or not. If exists iam gng to calculate jarowincler score for the individual attributes against the duplicates......

Comment: @Derek for inserting record into attachments, we need parentid which is nothing  but account record I'd.. I dnt want to add any I'd.

Comment: Assume I have 10k records in csv. For 10k records I hav to generate key which custom field in account formula name +phone, then I have to find duplicates based on key. If any duplicates are there. Then I have to calculate jarowincler score for a record for the key attributes....

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but if you upload the file to a property in apex and it is in css format you should be able to work directly with the property that holds the file and parse it without actually inserting it....just use a regular `<apex:inputFile>` component: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm